# How do I list loaded plugins in Vim?

Tags: vim, plugins

Does anybody know of a way to list up the "loaded plugins" in **Vim**?
I know I should be keeping track of this kind of stuff myself but
it would always be nice to be able to check the current status.

Answer (score 417, accepted):

Not a VIM user myself, so forgive me if this is totally offbase. But according to what I gather from the following [VIM Tips](http://rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html) site:

```
" where was an option set  
:scriptnames            : list all plugins, _vimrcs loaded (super)  
:verbose set history?   : reveals value of history and where set  
:function               : list functions  
:func SearchCompl       : List particular function
```

Answer (score 46):

The problem with `:scriptnames`, `:commands`, `:functions`, and similar Vim commands, is that they display information in a large slab of text, which is very hard to visually parse.

To get around this, I wrote [Headlights](https://github.com/mbadran/headlights), a plugin that adds a menu to Vim showing all loaded plugins, TextMate style. The added benefit is that it shows plugin commands, mappings, files, and other bits and pieces.

Comment: @Mohammed, I installed Headlights.  I'm on Mac OS X Mountain Lion, and I don't see menus in "vim".  I don't have a "gvim" in my path.  Any idea how to get/run a GUI vim that would show me menus so that I could see the Headlights menu?

Comment: @RobBednark MacVim is what your looking for. You can install it with HomeBrew via `brew install macvim` or get it [here](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/). You can activate it from the command line using `mvim` if you install that command line tool. (and you can alias that to `gvim` if you're used to typing that)

Comment: @adam_0 I have it as `brew cask install macvim`

Answer (score 34):

```
:set runtimepath?
```

This lists the path of all plugins loaded when a file is opened with Vim.

Comment: This doesn't list loaded plugins it lists runtime paths

Answer (score 27):

If you use [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim), `:PluginList`.

Answer (score 25):

:help local-additions

Lists local plugins added.

Comment: Note that this will only list plugins that have a proper vim help file installed

Comment: @jb Um I get a positive result for situations that say 'Sorry, no help for X'

Answer (score 14):

If you use [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) (Plug), "
A minimalist Vim plugin manager.":

```
:PlugStatus
```

That will not only list your plugins but check their status.